# Android Youtube Player in Fragment and Activity causes black screen

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity, android-youtube-api

I need to load a video in youtube player in an fragment (Consider it as Fragment A) as a header to a gridview in a fragment.Video is loading fine without any issue. But if i click on a grid item and loads seperate activity (Consider it as Activity B) in which there also, I am having youtube video player. It is playing fine in that activity. But when i come back to fragment from the activity B , now youtube player is not playing. Simply black screen is displaying.

FYI, 
I am having Fragment A in slidingMenu activity and activity B as activity.

For Fragment i am using **youtubesupportfragment** and in activity i am using **YoutubeBaseActivity**

Comment: How did you solve this? Facing same problem.

Comment: in my experience only solution might be to re-initialize the player on coming back

Comment: also you sometimes get black screen when pausing one player, then moving on to another player straight away (for example in full screen activity). In those cases it helps to call ```player.release()``` on the player you are leaving behind.

Comment: Above problem is resolved using different youtube API key on each activities