# YouTube API - Black screen in another activity

Tags: android, youtube-api

I would like to implement YouTube Player in my activities.

The scheme looks ***like this***:

[image: Click here]

My **java** Stopavid:

```
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer.Provider;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Stopavid extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

    public static final String DEVELOPER_KEY = "xxx";
    private static final String VIDEO_ID = "xxx";
    private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

    YouTubePlayerFragment myYouTubePlayerFragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.stopavid);
        myYouTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment)getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
        myYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format(
                    "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
                                        boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
// Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
        }
    }
    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
    }
}
```

and xml stopavid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is when I use this code in MainActivity creating new project, everything works. But when I try to put this in another activitiy then I have black screen.

[Click here - black screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8V7E.png)

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue. I'm suddenly experiencing it now when it was working fine before.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37990973/android-youtube-player-in-fragment-and-activity-causes-black-screen), sometimes you'll get black screen when pausing one player, then moving on to another player straight away (for example in full screen activity). Try to use `player.release()` on the player you are leaving behind before going to another activity. You may also check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494249/video-playback-displays-blank-screen-with-only-audio) if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I saw this already, but my problem is that I have black screen from the beginning